# Are there any differences between "I am sure" and "I was sure"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

I've heard people saying "*I was sure*" when it comes to confirming something in the past but my friend said that it should be "*I am sure*" since this action is happening in the present. Are there any differences after all?

Comment: What about the case where I _was_ sure but now I'm not?

Comment: I was sure I knew the answer to this, but I'm not so sure anymore.

Comment: Are there any differences between "I am young" and "I was young"?

Comment: You need to supply example sentences, saying why each causes you a problem. Context is very important here.

Answer (score 0):

We use the present tense 'I am sure' to discuss a present feeling, whether about a past, present, or future thing, for example 'I am sure that the moon landings were not a hoax', 'I am sure that my head is fixed to my shoulders', 'I am sure that my mother will win her table tennis match'. We would use the simple past to discuss a past feeling: 'I was sure that my mother would win her poker game, and I was right', 'I was sure that I could get to London before nightfall'. We would use the future tense to discuss a future feeling: 'I will be sure of having my new job when I get a formal offer of employment'.

Answer (score 0):

*I am sure* is used for current situations whre you are cartain about something.

> "I am sure I am ready for the test."

*I was sure* is used either for past situations where you were certain at the time and may or may not still be certain,

> "I was sure I was going to pass the test easily."

Or for a present situation where you were certain but are no longer so.

> "I was sure I had my keys in my pocket."